# How to Add Datatable Dynamically to div in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

in aspx page i have the div shown below

```
<div id="divID" runat="server" align="center"></div>
```

and i want to bind datatable dynamically to this div in c#

i tried it in code as

```
Datatable dtb=XXXX;
divID.Controls.Add(dtb);
```

Here I am getting the error as overload method has some invalid arguments.
syntax is wrong but how to add datatable.Please help me how to add or any suggestions.Thank You

Comment: Why don't you add a `GridView` control in the `<div>` tage and bind the got table from db in to it?

Comment: Is it not possible to add datatable directly to div?Actually i dont want gridview...

Comment: In which format? In a table format?

Comment: Datatable is not a control so you cannot add to a div

Answer (score 0):

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

// instantiate a datagrid
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
dg.DataSource = dataTable; //your dataTable
dg.DataBind();
dg.RenderControl(htw);
divID.InnerHtml = sw.ToString();
```

Here sw will give you the completely rendered html string. Sw can also be added to Response stream like response.Write(sw.ToString());

Hope it helps.